# How can an oscillating spin current in a nanostructure be observed or measured?

Tags: quantum-spin, magnetic-moment

Through calculation it's predicted there's pure spin current oscillating in a nanostructure. Here by "pure" I mean the charge current is zero. One can imagine two electrons of opposite spin are moving back and forth with the same amplitude and 180 degree phase shift.

The question is how such a phenomenon can be observed or measured in an experiment.

Comment: The same way you can measure any other spin: by coupling to an electromagnetic field trough the magnetic moment.

Comment: Thanks! I know a static magnetic moment in magnetic field will experience a torque. But for the oscillating moment what would be the typical effect?

Comment: This sounds like a possible application for an optical spin-echo experiment, but you are giving way too few details to link this to any particular technique.